# CSS Set width of an element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the width of an element `progress` to be the width between two other elements. Here is the HTML code I am using

```
      <span class="current_rank"><?php echo $this->current_rank;?></span>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="next_rank"><?php echo $this->next_rank;?></span>
```

I am trying to get the width of the progress bar to be the width between the two `<span>'s`
Is this possible with CSS?

Update

---

```
.progress {
  width: 550px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffd700;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
          transition: width 0.6s ease;
}

.VIP_ranking > .current_rank {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.VIP_ranking > .next_rank {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 22.5px;
}

.VIP_ranking > div.progress{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You need to show what you've tried. I'd suggest posting your css styles

Comment: added the CSS to the original post

Comment: all that css looks irrelevant to me. The class `VIP_ranking` is specified in your markup. While `current_rank` and `next_rank` is not specified in your css!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several CSS only solutions, but it really depends what are the requirements, in terms of browsers compatibility.

CSS calc function - you can use it if you know the width of the span elements, either the absolute width or the width in percentage. For example: width: calc(100% - 200px) or calc(80%). This solution will work in IE9+, Chrome and FF

Using display:flex; and justifying your content. You can read more about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/). You will not need to know the width of the spans, but this solution will only be compatible in IE10+, Chrome and FF.

Comment: I messed with that for a bit and it worked! Thanks! I ended up using the `display: flex;`